# How to preg_replace and keep parentheses value with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

I need to insert a JavaScript variable into the following line of JavaScript code, but this code will change with new ID's regularly so it needs to be able to simply keep the value in the parentheses and add my variable.

```js
AdobeEdge.loadComposition( '320x320', 'EDGE-12345678', {} );
```

In this case, I need to add variable `foo` into `320x320`, but keep in mind that `320x320` will change regularly and this is the result I am looking for.

```js
AdobeEdge.loadComposition( foo + '320x320', 'EDGE-12345678', {} );
```

I am using the following code to open my file:

```php
$txt = file_get_contents( $path . '/' . $fileinfo['basename'] );
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Fredrik

Comment: Is it always `loadComposition(` you want to append? If so no need for a regex use `str_replace`?

Comment: You are right, I did not think of that - cheers!